# Setting String value from either one object field

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception, option-type

How can I make my code look better?

I want to set String Name to ob1j.getX().getXX().getName() if it is present, otherwise I would set name to obj1.getY().getYY().getYYY().getName(). I'm also using Optional to perform null check.

Is this the correct way to do it ?

I'm using JDK8 so 'ifPresentOrElse' is not an option.

```
String Name = null;

Optional<String> optA = Optional.ofNullable(obj1.getX())
        .map(a -> a.getXX())
        .map(b -> b.getName())

if (optA.isPresent()) {
    name = optA.get();
} else {
    Optional<String> optB = Optional.ofNullable(obj1.getY())
        .map(a -> a.getYY())
        .map(b -> b.getYYY())
        .map(c -> c.getName())
    if (optB.isPresent()) {
        name = optB.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use ifPresent method instead Opt.ifPresent((name) -> // whatever you want name=Opt.get())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
name = Stream.of(
         Optional.ofNullable(obj1.getX()).map(X::getXX).map(XX::getName),
         Optional.ofNullable(obj1.getY()).map(Y::getYY).map(YY::getYYY).map(YYY::getName)
    )
     .filter(Optional::isPresent)
     .map(Optional::get)
     .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

---

Or for lazy processing you use `Supplier` like this:

```
List<Supplier<Optional<String>>> suppliers =Arrays.asList(
            () -> Optional.ofNullable(obj1.getX()).map(X::getXX).map(XX::getName),
  () -> Optional.ofNullable(obj1.getY()).map(Y::getYY).map(YY::getYYY).map(YYY::getName));

name = suppliers.stream()
            .map(Supplier::get)
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
```